# XML to CSV using Python

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, csv, beautifulsoup

I have XML file which I want to convert to CSV using Python. I need contents from the `Testitemname` tag as `CSV` headers and contents in the `Testvalue` tag as values in CSV.  Can some one help me with this?

Sample XML file (input)

```
<sample:batch xmlns:sample="http://sample.com/schema/sampleimport">
    <sample:TestData>
        <sample:Testitem>
            <sample:TestitemName>Field1</sample:TestitemName>
            <sample:Testvalue>1</sample:Testvalue>
        </sample:Testitem>
        <sample:Testitem>
            <sample:TestitemName>Field2</sample:TestitemName>
            <sample:Testvalue>Hi</sample:Testvalue>
        </sample:Testitem>
        <sample:Testitem>
            <sample:TestitemName>Field3</sample:TestitemName>
            <sample:Testvalue>1234</sample:Testvalue>
        </sample:TestData>
        <sample:TestData>
        <sample:Testitem>
            <sample:TestitemName>Field1</sample:TestitemName>
            <sample:Testvalue>3</sample:Testvalue>
        </sample:Testitem>
        <sample:Testitem>
            <sample:TestitemName>Field2</sample:TestitemName>
            <sample:Testvalue>Hello</sample:Testvalue>
        </sample:Testitem>
        <sample:Testitem>
            <sample:TestitemName>Field3</sample:TestitemName>
            <sample:Testvalue>999</sample:Testvalue>
        </sample:TestData>
```

Desired CSV file (Output)

```
Field1,Field2,Filed3 (Header field names)
1,Hi,1234 (1st record)
3,Hello,999 (2nd record)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BeautifulSoup` can be used to parse XML data.  With well organized data, you just need to loop over the nested tag types and collect the data as you go.

**Code:**

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup as Soup

def parse_xml(file_like):
    data = []
    names = []
    soup = Soup(file_like)
    for batch in soup.findAll('sample:batch'):
        for test_data in batch.findAll('sample:testdata'):
            item = {}
            for test_item in test_data.findAll('sample:testitem'):
                name = test_item.find('sample:testitemname').text
                value = test_item.find('sample:testvalue').text
                item[name] = value
                if name not in names:
                    names.append(name)
            data.append(item)

    return [names] + [[datum.get(name) for name in names] for datum in data]
```

**Test Code:**

```
data = parse_xml(xml_data)
for datum in data:
    print(','.join(datum))
```

**Test Data:**

```
from io import StringIO
xml_data = StringIO(u"""
    <sample:batch xmlns:sample="http://sample.com/schema/sampleimport">
        <sample:TestData>
            <sample:Testitem>
                <sample:TestitemName>Field1</sample:TestitemName>
                <sample:Testvalue>1</sample:Testvalue>
            </sample:Testitem>
            <sample:Testitem>
                <sample:TestitemName>Field2</sample:TestitemName>
                <sample:Testvalue>Hi</sample:Testvalue>
            </sample:Testitem>
            <sample:Testitem>
                <sample:TestitemName>Field3</sample:TestitemName>
                <sample:Testvalue>1234</sample:Testvalue>
        </sample:TestData>
        <sample:TestData>
            <sample:Testitem>
                <sample:TestitemName>Field1</sample:TestitemName>
                <sample:Testvalue>3</sample:Testvalue>
            </sample:Testitem>
            <sample:Testitem>
                <sample:TestitemName>Field2</sample:TestitemName>
                <sample:Testvalue>Hello</sample:Testvalue>
            </sample:Testitem>
            <sample:Testitem>
                <sample:TestitemName>Field3</sample:TestitemName>
                <sample:Testvalue>999</sample:Testvalue>
            </sample:TestItem>
        </sample:TestData>
    </sample:batch>
""")
```

**Results:**

```
Field1,Field2,Field3
1,Hi,1234
3,Hello,999
```

Comment: Thanks Stephen, it worked!! I would like to write output to a CSV file. Can you help me again?

Comment: The output I have shown is CSV... Just write to a file instead of printing to the screen

Answer (score 1):

Use pyxmlparser

It is a command line utility to do the same thing!

https://pypi.org/project/pyxmlparser/

Disclaimer: I am the author of the library. Since it is new I am more than happy to know if it worked.